# How to prevent a circuit from changing between browser tabs?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit

In the current versions of Tor (4.5.1) every time a new tab is opened a new circuit is made - causing the ip to change.

Consider the following scenarion:

1. User logs into firstsite.com - session/cookie data stores originating IP address among other credentials
2. User clicks on link at firstsite.com to access secondsite.com
3. firstsite.com sends IP address along with other credentials to secondsite.com
4. Authentication fails at secondsite.com because a new circuit has been formed in the new tab and the IP's no longer match.

I have tried TrackHostExits, MaxCircuitDirtiness, NewCircuitPeriod.  Is there any way to keep the same circuit across an entire browser session?

Comment: Have you found a way to do it? I'm having the same issues. I need to put the SocksPort line to the torrc? Because I tried that and didn't worked. Any step by step guide maybe?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `NoIsolateSOCKSAuth` isolation flag on the Tor Browser SocksPort, e.g.

```
SocksPort 9150 NoIsolateSOCKSAuth
```

Or, for a more limited approach, something like

```
MapAddress *.firstsite.com  *.firstsite.com.whatever.exit
MapAddress *.secondsite.com *.secondsite.com.whatever.exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TrackHostExits firstsite.com,secondsite.com` and `NoIsolateDestAddr` SocksPort options. It should keep your address AND don't separate the requests coming to the different addresses