# I can't register on twitch.tv with TOR beacuse image captcha loops itself

Tags: configuration

I am having a need to register a twitch.tv account with TOR (my static IP got blocked thanks to my brother) but i am experiencing issue with account creation. The form doesnt allow me to go forward beacuse of really bad design of ReCaptcha "I AM NOT A ROBOT" button that after getting clicked requires me to repeat and repeat the procedure of clicking road signs. I think it has something to do with constantly changing IP. I even replaced

```
SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
```

with

```
SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 NoIsolateSOCKSAuth
```

as described here: [How to prevent a circuit from changing between browser tabs?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/how-to-prevent-a-circuit-from-changing-between-browser-tabs) but i kept those IPv6 stuff in `torrc-defaults` file. Even after changing those prefs i STILL experience same issues with ReCaptcha. Any solutions?