# One random exit node/IP-address for each new TOR session (but common for all websites) - how to?

Tags: exit-relays, ip-address

Is it possible to keep one common exit node for all websites/domains during a TOR session? 
And this IP address should be different for each new TOR browsers sessions (i.e. random exit node).
I mean that the IP address changes when TOR restarts only.

I need this to test for a real exit IP address by different online services on different domains.

I know that it is possible to restrict an exit node to some country codes or IPs. But this is the manual solution (the manual editing of the torrc config each time), not an automatically selecting new exit nodes from a random pool. 
I know also how to keep one individual IP address for each domain, but not the common cross-website IP.

So, HOW to restrict the Tor for one cross-domain exit node, which should be chosen automatically each time when I launching the Tor?

Comment: Maybe the answers to https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/6855/88 help you.

Comment: Can you explain "I need this to test for a real exit IP address by different online services on different domains" further? I don't understand this sentence, and therefore why you're trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this but since this would totally break many of Tor's protections and stop you being anonymous, I will not help you shoot yourself in the foot.

Read the manual: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

Comment: I can't accept this imitation of an answer. First, this will NOT break "many" or break "totally" protections. Second, this will NOT stop anonymity of course... This slightly increase risks, but I know about this, so I will NOT use this configuration in dangerous cases.
Why you write the answer, if you don't know an answer? Any who use Tor know the manual and Google.
I found many answers about fixation of the last node in the Tor chain (to 1 static IP address). This is much dangerous, than the fixation of a new one every time when Tor restarts.

Comment: Alright, so don't accept it.

Comment: I have a use case where I don't give a damn if site A, B, and C, or the whole free world for that matter, are able to figure out I'm the same person, I just need the IP to be randomized *when I want it to be,* not every X minutes and certainly not for every domain - I actually *need* A, B, and C to see me from the *same* IP.  I've played with `TrackHostExits` and `IsolateDestAddr` to no avail.